# How to add vhost in docker apache server?

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose, dockerfile, virtualhost

Hi all and thanks for assistance

I want add virtual host to my apache server in docker but can not figure it out in the right way and does not work.
Do you know why ?

I'm using windows 10 operating system and [webdevops docker](https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile) image for php-apache.

my **docker-compose.yml**

```
www:
depends_on:
- mysql
- mail
image: webdevops/php-apache:7.4
volumes:
- "./www:/var/www/html"
- "./apache/vhost.conf:/opt/docker/etc/httpd/vhost.conf"
- "./apache/hosts:/etc/hosts"
environment:
- VIRTUAL_HOST=pharma.test,tests.dev
ports:
- 8080:80
env_file:
- .env
```

my **vhost.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName pharma.test
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pharma/public
```

Thanks all for your help